# How to find button with below definitions using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

below is defnition. How to find this button using selenium webdriver in Java

```
<button title="Add Role" class="p_AFHoverTarget x7j p_AFTextOnly" id="_FOpt1:_FOr1:0:_FONSr2:0:_FOTr1:3:pt1:cb1" onclick="this.focus();return false;">Add Role</button>
```

Comment: below is code for the button

Comment: <button title="Add Role" class="p_AFHoverTarget x7j p_AFTextOnly" id="_FOpt1:_FOr1:0:_FONSr2:0:_FOTr1:3:pt1:cb1" onclick="this.focus();return false;">Add Role</button>

Comment: Please edit your question to put in relevant information

Comment: Please post what you tried and what is the output?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the locators that you can use.

**xpath**

```
//button[@title='Add Role']
```

**CSS:**[preferred]

```
button[title='Add Role']
```